# Como calcular o Total via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Para mostrar os itens de uma venda utilizo um Json para mostrar os dados usando esse script.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {      
    var CodigoVenda = @ViewBag.CodigoVenda;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Venda/GetDadosItensVenda?Codigo="+ CodigoVenda,
        success: function (itensVenda) {

            if (itensVenda != null) {
                var total;

                $('#tbody').children().remove();

                $(itensVenda).each(function (i) {

                    total = (itensVenda[i].PrecoUnitario * itensVenda[i].Quantidade) + total;

                    var tbody = $('#tbody');
                    var tr = "<tr>";
                    tr +=
                    tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].Codigo;
                    tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].CodigoProduto;
                    tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].Quantidade;
                    tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].PrecoUnitario;
                    tr += "<td>" + (itensVenda[i].PrecoUnitario * itensVenda[i].Quantidade);
                    tbody.append(tr);
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Como podemos ver, para saber o SubTotal eu faço o (ValorUnitario * Quantidade)
Minha dúvida é como somar o TOTAL de todos os itens, para informar o valor de venda.

Comment: O que dá `console.log(typeof itensVenda[i].PrecoUnitario, typeof itensVenda[i].Quantidade)`?

Comment: Não entendi. Você já está somando o total aqui: `total = (itensVenda[i].PrecoUnitario * itensVenda[i].Quantidade) + total;`.

Comment: Como faço para passar esse valor para um elemento HTML?

Comment: Para passar para html , ficaria $("#id_elemento_html").html(valor);   -> $("#total_html").html(total);  . Em seu código html , para exibir você usa : <span id="total_html"></span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema é que você não especificou o valor inicial da variável total, então quando ele vai tentar fazer atribuição ele retorna um **NaN** (não é um número), basta você atribuir um valor número que o seu código funciona:

```
var total = 0;
```

Você também pode somar os valor usando o operador `+=`

```
total += (itensVenda[i].PrecoUnitario * itensVenda[i].Quantidade);
```

**Exemplo funcional:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwwg1gs0/)

Comment: Com o seu exemplo eu consegui fazer, obrigado!